# what is best data mining technique and good accuracy in time series?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-mining, dataset

i beginner in data mining in my company and i want to do some prediction in our stock , the stock contain products that have nay and sale every time , 
i want to make some prediction about best sales time,best price and so on , what is the best to use time series prediction with good accuracy 
neural network  or time series algorithm like Arima

Comment: This seems very broad. Can you narrow it down a bit to a more specific question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Long-short term memory (lstm) is the state is the art in the time series.

If you want something superadvanced, check out the combination of recurrent neural networks with adversarial learning: https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.09904